# MySQL search/replace with '\/'

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I am using the WYSIWYG builder Unyson in WordPress. I moved my site to a new domain and have discovered that Unyson saves forward slashes `/` in the database with an escape backslash before it `\/`.

I need to search for specific URLs that have an insecure HTTP and replace them with HTTPS, but if I search with:

```
SELECT * from table_name WHERE column_name like '%http\/\/www.domain.com%';
```

It doesn't return anything.

If I search for just `\/\/`:

```
SELECT * from table_name WHERE column_name like '%\/%';
```

I do get a return.

But I need to search for the specific domain that has HTTP and replace it with HTTPS.

Using the `\/\/` in the middle of the like statement doesn't return anything. I have tried to use `\\\/`, but it doesn't work.

How can I search for the domain with `\/\/` inside the string and get a result?

Comment: TL;DR: you need to use `\\\\/` inside a `LIKE` expression

Answer (score 0):

You could try using NOT LIKE 'https%'

```
SELECT * from table_name WHERE column_name NOT like 'https%';
```